# If two same character occurs, remove first and everything before it?

Tags: php, string, wordpress, str-replace, substr

In Wordpress I have built shortcode which shorten url. Now there is problem if the url is a subdomain, for example: `http://cdn.livestream.com/embed/channel`, by shortcode function I get this:
`<a href="http://cdn.livestream.com/embed/channel" target="_blank">cdn.livestream.com</a>`

As you can see there is `cdn.livestream.com`, and I only want it to be `livestream.com`. I am not an expert in this, I know I need a function which should do this:"If two fullstops are occurring in a string, remove first and everything before it, I guess." I am using this function:

```
function url( $atts, $content = null ) {
$cnt = substr($content, 0, strpos($content, '/', strpos($content, '/')+2));
$cnt = str_replace('http://www.', '', $cnt);
$cnt = str_replace('http://', '', $cnt);
$cnt = str_replace('www.', '', $cnt);
$cnt = str_replace('embed.', '', $cnt);
$cnt = str_replace('player.', '', $cnt);
$cnt = str_replace('//', '', $cnt);
$cnt = str_replace('feature=player_embedded&', '', $cnt);
    return '<div id="url"><a href="/external/?link='.$content.'" target="_blank">'.$cnt.'</a></div>';
}
add_shortcode("url", "url");
```

Huge part could be changed I think, all this:

```
$cnt = str_replace('http://www.', '', $cnt);
$cnt = str_replace('http://', '', $cnt);
$cnt = str_replace('www.', '', $cnt);
$cnt = str_replace('embed.', '', $cnt);
$cnt = str_replace('player.', '', $cnt);
$cnt = str_replace('//', '', $cnt);
```

Comment: So google.co.uk should be co.uk then?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. If google.co.uk, output co.uk, and if co.uk, again output co.uk

Comment: Seriously? *"Here's a link to Google: [co.uk](http://google.co.uk)."* Looks weird to me. But suit yourself... :)

Comment: "Watch this channel on: livestream.com." I will not use function for google link, but many video or tv sites using subdomains to provide embed code.

Comment: Well, my point is that you're trying to find the "canonical parent domain name", but that is not necessary always one with only a single `.` in it. It may work for *many* sites, but will have weird results for *some* if you do it this naively.

Comment: I think to use two separate shortcodes, one for sites which are on subdomains, like google.co.uk, and this one for sites which provide embed content from subdomain and are located on domain. As you said maybe I should leave this as it is. Just remove some str_replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using [parse_url($url);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$cnt = 'http://cdn.livestream.com/embed/channel';
print_r(parse_url($cnt));
echo parse_url($cnt, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => cdn.livestream.com
    [path] => /embed/channel
)
```

then use the host section of the array.

```
echo str_replace('cdn.','',$cnt['host']);
```

hopefully some what helpful! :)

Marty

Comment: $cnt = parse_url($content, PHP_URL_HOST);

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode function,

```
$str = "http://cdn.ecospace.com"

$explode = explode("//", $str);

$nextExplode = explode (".", $explode[1]);

$finalStr = "";
if (count($nextExplode)>2) {

   $finalStr = $explode[0]."//".$nextExplode[1].".".$nextExplode[2];
} else {
   $finalStr = $str;
}
echo $finalStr;
```